# kthreaddi process is causing a high CPU usage

Tags: oracle

I'm using REDHAT 7.6 as an OS on my server and top command shows high CPU usage from kthreaddi process without obvious reason, now my solution is down, and also my Fusion middleware (I'm using ORACLE as database )
any solutions

[image: TOP RESULTS]

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this problem a few days ago, the quickest solution I could get was the following:

Use the following command:

```
ls -l /proc/<PID_of_process>/exe
```

This command shows the position where the process is running.
Create this folder.

Remove all the permissions for all users:

```
chmod o-rwx /tmp/<name_of_folder>
```

Then kill the process:

```
kill -9 <PID_of_process>
```

Comment: In my case, it had a parent process that name was numeric.

First i found the directory with your first command. Then killed the parent process and finally killed the kthreadd processes.

Thanks dear Carlos

Answer (score 1):

Kindly run below one liner bash shell script inside crontab every minute and it will kill the virus in a scripted way.

```
kill -9 $((ps -aux | grep -i 'kdevtmpfsi\|kinsing\|kthreaddi') 2>/dev/null |grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}')
```